# Load Balanced Rest Template

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, netflix-eureka

I have two instances of Eureka server and each server has different services (multiple instances) registered in it. I have a client application that makes rest calls to the services registered in each of the Eureka servers. I'm using a rest template to make rest calls to these services through service name. LoadBalanced rest template is not working in this case. I need inputs on how to achieve this.

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

This is the rest template I have. I have two different Eureka servers that are purely independent. I want my application to be able to talk to applications registered with both of these servers using service-name and rest template.

Comment: Can you add relevant part of the code?

Comment: Are ribbon and eureka-ribbon in classpath?

Comment: yes, they are, Added my rest template too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. This is another example of how to get the instance and send a request. Let me know whether this helps.

Properties changes
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=eureka **server1** url,eureka **server2** url2

This will Load balance between Eureka and Instances.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient;

    public String calDirectly(String name){

        ServiceInstance serviceinstance = loadBalancerClient.choose("<service name>");

            ResponseEntity<String> restExchange =
                    restTemplate.exchange(
                            "http://"+serviceinstance.getHost()+":"+serviceinstance.getPort()+"<url & other parameter>",
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            null, String.class, name);

            return restExchange.getBody();
    }

}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It is sharing the registry between the 2 eureka servers. This shouldn't happen for me as they are 2 different Eureka servers and they shouldn't share registry.

Comment: I add some `LoadBalancerClients` annotation config and it worked. but it would be better by using load balanced rest template instead of usage of `loadBalancerClient` manually

Answer (score 2):

Your client must be registered on Eureka server too.
Only then calling service by name will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring ZUUL as Gateway it will load balance the request Automatically. Or Programmatically can be done using below code

LoadBalanced is part of spring cloud commons https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons

```
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;

@Bean
@LoadBalanced
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Comment: I'm using the restTemplate bean you have mentioned but it's not working with multiple Eureka servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when I created 3 services and a discovery server and wanted to use one of the services to call the other two using `@LoadBalanced` and `RestTemplate`

**This is how I fixed it:**

In the application.properties file of all the eureka clients, I had to add this -->

`eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true`

and that fixed it for me